# Do synced folder on vagrant have a drive prefix automatically?

Tags: bash, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am currently setting up a vagrant box and adding different synced folders.
I am using Windows 7 and working from a cygwin bash environment.

Upon starting my vagrant box I can see the following output of my synced_folder:

```
=> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /home/vagrant/db => C:/Develop/projects/t-vagrant/trunk/src/main/resources/db
```

Note that there is a fixed drive prefix on my path, that is here **C:**

My Vagrantfile config object is this:

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "/Develop/projects/t-vagrant/trunk/src/main/resources/db", "/home/vagrant/db/", :create => "true"
```

I have my cygwin fstab to be configured that my `harddrive c` is under **/c/**
Anyhow, using a full-qualified path in the Vagrantfile does not give me access to the contents of the host, mainly because vagrant seems to add the **C:** prefix to it.

Am I missing any configuration that tells Vagrant to discard that C: ? I mean, if I would like to include folders from other drives this would not work when the prefix is set.

Comment: isnt `/cygdrive/X` (replace X with the drive you need to access) the path to access the other drive ? can you try with that ?

Comment: yes and no. Normally it is, but I reconfigure this to discard /cygdrive/ upon fstab. anyhow this should not be the reason why there is windows-style C: prefix as fstab just does the mapping of the path upon mounting time :-(